# Python 3.6.0 execution gets stuck on importlib.import_module

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-importlib

I'm using python 3.6.0 with PyCharm Edu 4.0.2 in debug mode, walking through the code it stops while trying to load a script with

```
module = importlib.import_module(module_name,package_name)
```

where package_name = '' and module_name = file_name.py

I tried the following but no error is thrown even if I let it run for an hour

```
try:
    module = importlib.import_module(module_name,package_name)
except Exception as e:
    self._logger.error(e)
```

It seems that the issue has something to do with another import in the module being imported:

```
from filterpy.common import Q_discrete_white_noise
```

I have installed filterpy 1.4.5.

If I comment out the filterpy import the module import works.

Comment: Pressing control-c while it is hanging should produce a full stack trace - including where in `Q_discrete_white_noise` it is hanging. Can you add a full stack trace (from control-c) to your question?

Comment: If I set a breakpt on the line where it gets stuck and ctrl-c some I see a random error on the console.   

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Edu 4.0.2\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_vars.py", line 354, in evaluate_expression
    compiled = compile(expression, '<string>', 'eval')
  File "<string>", line 1
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: I also tried to debug the import module and found out the it gets stuck on `return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)`